# Use 'dd' to split the binary apart and extract the parts

Tags: linux-kernel, binary, arm, embedded-linux, u-boot

I have firmware file in .bin format, but need to obtain the romimage.img and Kernel uImage files required to reflash a bricked device. 
I used Binwalk to identify different parts of a firmware binary, `$ binwalk firmware.bin`

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
392           0x188           uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0xEF73A583, created: 1969-12-31 23:59:59, image size: 1572736 bytes, Data Address: 0x20008000, Entry Point: 0x20008000, data CRC: 0x3661C6EC, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: "SP2Xcybertan_rom_bin"
13596         0x351C          gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 2019-04-03 05:25:36
1573192       0x180148        uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x9053B22D, created: 1969-12-31 23:59:59, image size: 8474624 bytes, Data Address: 0x0, Entry Point: 0x0, data CRC: 0xFC8655E0, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: Filesystem Image, compression type: none, image name: "SP2Xcybertan_rom_bin"
1573256       0x180188        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, non-standard signature, version 3.1, size: 8473072 bytes, 1028 inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: 2019-04-03 05:36:06
```

from boot log:

```
Loading from NAND 32MiB 3,3V 8-bit, offset 0x80000
   Image Name:   SP2Xcybertan_rom_bin
   Created:      1970-01-01   0:00:-1 UTC
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    1572736 Bytes =  1.5 MB
   Load Address: 20008000
   Entry Point:  20008000
    ... ... ... ...

Creating 11 MTD partitions on "gen_nand":
0x00000000-0x00060000 : "u-boot"
0x00060000-0x00080000 : "u-bootenv"
0x00080000-0x01460000 : "ROMIMAGE"
0x01460000-0x01b60000 : "HALFIMAGE"
0x00200000-0x01460000 : "LINUX_ROOTFS"
   ... ... ... ...
```

Now I need to split the firmware image apart and extract the Rom Image romimage.img and kernel uImage from firmware.bin: how to make this properly use linux `dd` command?

Comment: I don't know how you work out the offset and size of the portion you want to extract, but once you have found them, then use `dd bs=1 skip=THEOFFSET count=THELENGTH if=INPUTFILENAME of=OUTPUTFILENAME`. (`THEOFFSET` and `THELENGTH` need to be in decimal.)

Comment: `binwalk` has an `-e` option to extract and `-dd` to extract the files.  I would guess you don't need the offsets and sizes to pass to `dd` if you use this.  You have to be careful.. The linux may have DT, initramfs (SQUSHFS, etc) attached.  Sometimes you may only get the code.  Also u-boot is going to work better with the [uImage format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122526/how-to-convert-a-zimage-into-uimage-for-booting-with-u-boot).

Comment: `man split` should help you.